# Laravel Controller request array empty for Route with Parameters

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, seo

I want to have an SEO friendly url's for this I made a jquery function where I visit the web page. like mentioned in blade.php.

The parameters are successfully passed in the url but I am not receiving it on controller side. and display empty or null .

index.blade.php

```
var v_href      = "http://mywebsite.com/program/course/"+discipline+"/"+city+"/"+discipline_id+"/"+city_id;
v_href          = v_href.replace('--', '-');
window.location.href = v_href;
```

Route file

web.php

```
Route::get('/program/course/{discipline?}/{city?}/{discipline_id?}/{city_id?}', 'FinderController@index')->name('finder.index');
```

Controller function

```
            $discipline_id  = $request->input('discipline_id');
            $city_id        = $request->input('city_id');
```

but I am getting null in both variables

Comment: And what exactly is the URL that gives you the `NULL` values?

Comment: for all urls , couldn't get any data seem like the $request is empty .

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve route parameters, you have to add them as arguments to your controller function. So, in your case say the function is called `getSource()` you can do this:

```
public function getSource(?string $discipline = null, ?string $city = null, ?int $discipline_id = null, ?int $city_id = null)
{
    dd($discipline, $city, $discipline_id, $city_id);
}
```

Comment: there is also another parameter like 
$request->except('page') for pagination

Comment: That's different, that's a query parameter which you should get through the `$request` variable

Comment: it worked with `public function index(Request $request, ?string $discipline = null, ?string $city = null, ?int $discipline_id = null, ?int $city_id = null)
 {`

thanks :)